# Black screen when i run my application on the device

Tags: iphone, ios

On the simulator, all is Ok, when i make an ipa and install it on the device and then try to run the application, i got a black screen, even the splash screen is not shown. Does any one ran into the same issue?

Comment: Does it stay on the black screen or does it immediately go back to Springboard? Also, what iOS version and are you testing on the equivalent simulator?

Comment: and does your device's log (which you can see in the Xcode organizer) say anything useful?

Comment: @mattjgalloway: what's the Springboard? --For the iOS version, the simulator is set up to the iOS 5 and so the device.

Comment: 5.0 on both? Springboard is the main home screen of an iOS device. i.e. the thing where you select an app to launch.

Comment: Yeah, 5.0 on both, the deployment target and the device.